# Theming search page

Tags: 7, blocks, search

I'm customizing my search results page. I have found the two templates `search-result.tpl` and `search-results.tpl` but in addition to these there is also a collapsible `fieldset` for advanced search. Where is this coming from? How can I theme the page as a whole? Like do it in a `page.tpl` or `node.tpl` file.

Also `Themer` tells me that this whole node (the search page content) is actually a `block.tpl` file! How is that possible?

I'm on D7.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hey Ali, could you include some code of the pages with the fieldset?

Comment: @Mike Why is there a need for code? The html for the page is a huge mess and I don't think there is enough room on this forum page to put it here. ;)

Comment: @Ali I might have been able to point out where the field set comes from.

Answer (score 2):

The collapsible fieldset comes from FAPI and is a different thing than the search results.

It's a regular form, so you have to alter it the form way, via hooks. The basics are [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

```
function your_module_name_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)) {
  if ($form_id === 'search_block_form') {  // Double check it's the correct ID
      // Your custom code goes here
      // Starting with a dpm($form) is often a good idea
  }
}
```

Comment: That's true. But from where does Drupal display the fieldset in the search page because I'm not customizing the form itself? I'm guessing (I could be wrong though) that there might be a template file or something that handles the display of the whole search results content. Where is that?

Comment: The fieldset is part of the form, so you should be able to acces it via this [hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/template_preprocess_search_block_form/7).

Answer (score 1):

You can of course try the default from theme method like [Theming forms in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1067612)

```
$form['#theme'] = 'foo-login-form';
```

with `hook_form_alter`

Comment: The source of the file you suggest has only one line of code i.e, `<?php print $search_form; ?>`.

And this doesn't tell where the `fieldset` is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

The field set you are seeing is added from [`node_form_search_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_form_search_form_alter/7), a [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) implementation, which uses the following code.

```php
  if (isset($form['module']) && $form['module']['#value'] == 'node' && user_access('use advanced search')) {
    // Keyword boxes:
    $form['advanced'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Advanced search'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array(
          'search-advanced',
        ),
      ),
    );
    $form['advanced']['keywords'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="criterion">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    $form['advanced']['keywords']['or'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Containing any of the words'),
      '#size' => 30,
      '#maxlength' => 255,
    );
    $form['advanced']['keywords']['phrase'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Containing the phrase'),
      '#size' => 30,
      '#maxlength' => 255,
    );
    $form['advanced']['keywords']['negative'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Containing none of the words'),
      '#size' => 30,
      '#maxlength' => 255,
    );

    // Node types:
    $types = array_map('check_plain', node_type_get_names());
    $form['advanced']['type'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => t('Only of the type(s)'),
      '#prefix' => '<div class="criterion">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#options' => $types,
    );
    $form['advanced']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Advanced search'),
      '#prefix' => '<div class="action">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#weight' => 100,
    );

    // Languages:
    $language_options = array();
    foreach (language_list('language') as $key => $entity) {
      if ($entity->enabled) {
        $language_options[$key] = $entity->name;
      }
    }
    if (count($language_options) > 1) {
      $form['advanced']['language'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Languages'),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="criterion">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#options' => $language_options,
      );
    }
    $form['#validate'][] = 'node_search_validate';
  }
```

To theme a form, you just need to add code similar to the following one.

```php
function mymodule_form_search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['module']) && $form['module']['#value'] == 'node') {
    $form['#theme'] = 'mymodule_search_form';
  }
}
```

The theme function could be one using a template file.
The control statement is necessary to add the theme function only to the search form for nodes. If you need to alter all the search pages, then it should be removed; if you need to change another search page, then change the `$form['module']['#value'] == 'node'` part.

Drupal shows the *Advanced search* fieldset only when the logged-in user has the "use advanced search" permission. That should be kept in consideration, as the *Advanced search* fieldset could not be added to the form.

Answer (score 1):

The search module outputs a render array to $page['content'] with two parts

```
$page['content']['search_form']
$page['content']['search_results']
```

You can intercept this array in your theme before it gets rendered and make modifications to it.

i.e in your theme_preprocess_page you can do

```
$page['content']['search_form']['#suffix'] = 'Hello'
```

To insert hello below the form. You can also modify the contents of the arrays directly if you want to change the way they behave.

You will need some logic in there to make sure it exists before making changes. But this is just an example.

Hope that makes sense, there is no single template that surrounds these that you can access directly.